# InputStream blocks when reading large amount of data from external process

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have some problem with getting data prom `Process.exec()` 
There is a process that I must call from Java, that can work for a very long time, and this process can produce large amount of data. 
What I was doing for now was this:

```
public InputStream exec() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
    return p.getInputStream();
}
```

This code blocks after it runs for some time. I assume that the InputStream buffer is being filled, and it's waiting for me to read from it. 
I want to return InputStream since this output can, but not must, be compressed, so I could decompress this output later, and I must read this output as byte output stream 
How can I run this process and get it's output data?

Comment: Urrmmm ... It is the `waitFor` method that blocks, isn't it?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Yeah, it waits for the process to terminate. My external process allways terminates.